# how to support custom graphics in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, ios6

How to support custom graphics in iPhone 5, 4 inches display.
I know that for Default it's need to add -568h prefix and it's work when my status bar is hidden and my background image size is 640 x 1136 px. But when I need to add custom background for the screen that size smaller then 1136 px it doesn't work.
So how to support custom graphics in new retina display?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use my three `#define`s:

```
#define isPhone568 ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
#define iPhone568ImageNamed(image) (isPhone568 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h", image] : image)
#define iPhone568Image(image) ([UIImage imageNamed:iPhone568ImageNamed(image)])
```

Just give your images the -568h@2x.png notation, and use `iPhone568ImageNamed` to get a name for standard name or iPhone 5/new iPod.