# iPhone 4(s), iPhone 5, iPhone 3GS compatible app now

Tags: xcode, ios6

Now that iOS 6 and iPhone 5 are out I'm a little confused with how to adjust user interface to all of the iPhones. When I develop an app should I have two separate xibs for iPhone 5 and older iPhones? When putting images should I still add suffix @2x when for retina? I guess that for retina of the new iPhone it will be -568@2x? Could you please tell me about this briefly? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do a lot of specific work, really. Just implement your XIB files with correct autoresizing masks. If you are targeting iOS 6 only, you can use autolayout, otherwise you cannot. Images continue to function the same way - for 3GS and iPad 1/2 you name your images "xyz.png" and for retina display devices (which include iPhone 4,4S,5 and iPad 3) you give the @2x suffix "xyz@2x.png". The "-568" notation is currently only supported for the launch image. Indeed, if you place a "xyz-568@2x.png" image and attempt to use it as "xyz" on iPhone 5, it will not be discovered.

If you need to have a special background image for iPhone 5/iPod 5, you can use [my macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519040/983912) with that "-568@2x.png" notation.